# LinkedIN URL decoding

Tags: url, linkedin-api, decode

In LinkedIN, these codes, found in the URL (one by URL):

```
ACwAAAFX3cUB_8VkdrflK8rsvnKYiezfErHYgUA
ACwAAAEKW6UBiVnYhd5eRAV4ZnTD_exLPsFdl_8
ACwAAACBf2kBP6-WdZCP7ZYMusa_s-DIM1TksUQ
ACwAAAAK5kwBgLjKXRS19PWD8PjzNCTdldwPRuM
```

are going to be converted in user names.

Can anyone tell me if this is an encoding, encryption, hash or what?
And how to 'decode' it?

I tried with base64, but I didn't get to a result.

Thanks!

Comment: no such thing as "unhashing" -> https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Comment: Please suggest a title. I think 'decoding' is also inaccurate

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm also having the same problem